# h2o - Tweedie response link function

Tags: h2o

I'm using h2o.gbm, and i'm specifying a tweedie distribution.  The response should logged, and I think by specifying a tweedie distribution that h2o will log the response.  Given the following from the documentation:

> When specifying the distribution, the loss function is automatically
>   selected as well. For exponential families (such as Poisson, Gamma, and
>   Tweedie), the canonical logarithmic link function is used.

However, tweedie distributions have a point mass of 0.  So if h2o is logging the response, is it actually logging the response variables when the value is 0 or is there some other transformation?  such as:

`data[,"new_response"] <- h2o.if_else(data$response == 0, 0, log(data$response))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response value is set to .1, to prevent taking the log of 0. You can find the line of code where this takes place [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/glm/GLMModel.java#L419).

`double y1 = yr == 0?.1:yr;`